# Detect Samsung Tab as USB Modem using gnome-ppp

Tags: gnome, samsung, usb-modem, tethering, ppp

I exploit internet in PC by tethering USB from Samsung Tab2 : 
[image]

Internet works fine , however, i cannot configure this device as usb modem using `gnome-ppp` 
[image]
[image]

i set `/dev/ttyS0` , because when i run this cmd

```
ls -l /dev/ttyS0
```

i get  :

[image]

Known that i saw this  [documentation](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/telephone_modem)but no result :

does `gnome-ppp` requires some configurations before using it , such as , `setserial` or what and how?

**UDPATE :**

Log :

[image]

Comment: You may have to add yourself to group `dialout`